# XSL:FO - Dynamic Content, Specific Footer on Page 1

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I've currently got a document that is being generated through xsl:fo. In this document, I have a header in my region-before, all my content in region-body (note that the content spans up to 5 pages long), and my footer in region-after. My footer consists of a logo and a slogan, but I only want the logo to appear in the footer on the first page.

I am unable to use conditional-page-master as all the content in region-body is dynamically spread out. The content length stays the same but due to a section in the first page which has a variable size, the content gets spread out accordingly. Any suggestions of how to have the footer on the first page be different than the footers on the other pages? Aside from conditional-page-master if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your problem with `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_conditional-page-master-reference), but you could do what you want with an `fo:marker` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_marker) containing your logo and slogan at the start of your flow, and in the `fo:static-content` for your footer, use `fo:retrieve-marker` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_retrieve-marker) to retrieve them.

The initial value of `retrieve-position` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#retrieve-position) is `first-starting-within-page`, so with only one `fo:marker` at the start of your content, the logo and slogan should appear only in the footer of the first page.